# Help me identify this Beetle sp?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I observed many beetles like this in **Pune/India** in the beginning of rainy season. It was dark green in color with white spots and not too much shiny like many other beetles. Size is about 2cm to 3cm.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly a scarab, in subfamily Cetoniinae. It looks very much like a White Spotted Fruit Chafer, *Mausoleopsis amabilis* http://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/11819281

Comment: Thanks for above link from which I found this [species](https://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/show/352860) (Protaetia alboguttata). It seems correct identification.